# standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory" from using net/http package

Tags: docker, go

Steps to reproduce the problem:

1. `main.go` is using `net/http`.

```
docker build -o . main.go   // This generates the main executable.
```

2. Now preparing one Dockerfile

```
 FROM alpine:3.6
 ENTRYPOINT ["/home/myhome/main"]
```

3. Then, `docker build -t myimag3`
4. Now when I run this image

```
docker run -it -v /home/myhome:/home/myhome myimage
```

it results in the following error:

```
getting : standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "no such file or directory"
```

I am facing this problem because of the main executable from `main.go`. If i remove all content and simply putting `fmt.Println("Hello world")` then it is working properly.
Only thing is when I try to use `net/http` packages at that time it is giving this error.
I am new to this go lang. Can anybody please provide some suggestions?

Code to `main.go`

```
https://tutorialedge.net/golang/go-docker-tutorial/
```

Comment: Please share your Dockerfile as well.

Comment: You get this error because you built out a dynamic linked binary. Looks like an executable missing a library. In this case, the net import brings in libc by default, as a dynamic linked binary. You can use `CGO_ENABLED=0` to build your binary statically.

Comment: I tried creating my main build using CGO_ENABLED=0 go build -o . main.go  then it is working properly. Thank you for quick suggestion.